# Запятая перед союзом "пока"

Tags: пунктуация, спп, союзы

Нужна ли запятая перед союзом "пока"?

*Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на то, что данное приглашение действительно(,) пока есть свободные места.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Данное приглашение действительно, пока есть свободные места.**

Это сложноподчинённое предложение, "есть свободные места" - придаточное, "пока" - подчинительный союз. Придаточные предложения отделяются от главного запятыми.

Примеры.
Литература существует, п. она понятна. Сердце любит до тех пор, п. не истратит своих сил  ([Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0&all=x)).

Answer (score 0):

Запятая нужна, т. к. это союз.

Comment: Настасья не сомневалась и днём раньше, что — союз. Перед союзом всегда ставится зпт?

Answer (score -2):

Пока — наречие, выражающее обстоятельство времени. Разве "пока" — это союз?